# Getting price from multiple select boxes

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jquery script that I am using to build an appointment system for a client. The data-price represents the actual price of the services rendered. I need to be able to combine that result with the other drop-downs rather then just take whatever data-price is selected

**jQuery**

```
$("select").change(function(){
   var price = parseFloat($(this).find("option:selected").data("price"));
   if(isNaN(price))
       price = 0;
   var currPrice = parseFloat($("strong").data("price"));
   $("strong").text('$ ' + currPrice + price );
})
```

**Relevant HTML (using Laravel 4 blade template to call database table)**

```
<div id="rm_clean" class="tab-pane fade in active">
       Areas:<br />
   <select name="rooms"> 
        <option value="" selected="selected">0</option>
         @foreach ($room as $rooms)
         <option data-price="{{ $rooms->pr_clean }}" value='{{ $rooms->room  }}'>{{ $rooms->room  }}</option>
         @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div id="rm_deodorize" class="tab-pane fade">
       Deodorizer:<br />
   <select name="pr_deodorizer"> 
        <option value=''>0</option>
         @foreach ($room as $rooms)
            <option data-price="{{ $rooms->pr_deodorizer }}" value='{{ $rooms->pr_deodorizer  }}'>{{ $rooms->room  }}</option>
         @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div id="rm_protectent" class="tab-pane fade">
        Protectant:<br />
    <select name="pr_protectant"> 
        <option value=''>0</option>
         @foreach ($room as $rooms)
            <option data-price="{{ $rooms->pr_protectant }}" value='{{ $rooms->pr_protectant  }}'>{{ $rooms->room  }}</option>
         @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div id="rm_sanitizer" class="tab-pane fade">
        Sanitizer:<br />
    <select name="pr_sanitizer"> 
        <option value=''>0</option>
         @foreach ($room as $rooms)
            <option  value='{{ $rooms->pr_sanitizer  }}'>{{ $rooms->room  }}</option>
         @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<strong data-price="0">$</strong>
```

I want to beable to combine the other drop-downs not the same ones. If I choose 1 room in the drop-down and then 5 in that same drop-down I don't want it to count 6. I do need it to count the rooms and then the other drop-downs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy fix is to iterate through all the selects on the change, else you need to maintain the previously selected value for each select then subtract it from `currPrice` then add current value

```
var $selects = $("select").change(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $selects.each(function () {
        var price = parseFloat($(this).find("option:selected").data("price")) || 0;
        total += price;
    })
    $("strong").text('$ ' + total);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/S6sym/)

Comment: That looks like that worked! Your a master of your craft! I should have no problems adding in other prices to this thanks a ton!

Comment: @user2267668 another messy solution can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yMq7K/1/

Comment: I might need to ask another question on SO but if I wanted to show right below the price what they just chose. Areas: X <br /> Deodorizer: X...etc how can I go about that with the awesome code you provided (in the first fiddle)

Comment: @user2267668 you can have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xf9Fp/2/ but don't forget to ask it as a question

Comment: yea, I can maybe work with that. I will ask another question though. I need it to show the actual name of the service which is not in the drop-down. Keep a look out so you can get credit I will be using your fiddle as my example. Thanks again bud!

Comment: @user2267668 add a link to the question here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660574/trying-to-show-selected-services-on-price-calculator