# Trying to show selected services on price calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working example of a simple price calculator that pulls the price from a database (via Laravel 4 and Blade template engine) and a customer can select the services and the price calculator will output the price.

It works very well however I would like it to show the selected services right below the price. An example I have is here but not exactly what I was looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xf9Fp/2/

```
    var $selections = $('#selections');
var $selects = $("select").change(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $selections.empty();
    $selects.each(function () {
        var $selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
        var price = parseFloat($selected.data("price")) || 0;
        total += price;
        if($selected.val() !== ''){
            $('<li />', {
                text: $selected.text() + ':' + $selected.val()
            }).appendTo($selections)
        }
    })
    $("strong").text('$ ' + total);
})
```

How I would like it to work is:

Price: $X (<-- this part works fine)

> if they select  2 rooms and 1 room deodorizer and nothing else. I want it to show

Your order:

Rooms: 2 
Deodorizer: 1

that why they can have a breakdown of the services they just selected. Also of course if the de-select let's say deodorizer I would want all that to clear except the rooms (or whatever is left)

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/xf9Fp/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
$('<li />', {
            text: $(this).parent().clone().children().remove().end().text()+" "+$selected.text() + ':' + $selected.val()
        }).appendTo($selections)
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xf9Fp/5/)

Comment: I went with yours thanks a lot! I do sometimes have issues with what looks like rounded numbers. For instances this number comes up sometimes. 959.1999999999999 as a price. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var $selections = $('#selections');
var $selects = $("select").change(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $selections.empty();
    $selects.each(function () {
        var $selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
        var price = parseFloat($selected.data("price")) || 0;
        total += price;
        if($selected.val() !== ''){
            $('<li />', {
                text: $selected.text() + ':' + $selected.val()
            }).appendTo($selections)
        }
    })
    $("strong").text('$ ' + total);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xf9Fp/)

Answer (score 0):

this was made easy by adding `id`'s to your select boxes, heres the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xf9Fp/3/)